# how can I fix httplib2, oauth2client and apiclient libraries not importing in vscode python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gmail-api

this is my import codes, and I pip install all the files I should:

```
from apiclient import errors, discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client, tools, file
import httplib2
```

And this is the error for all of them:

```
Import "httplib2" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
Import "oauth2client" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Import "apiclient" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

I use windows system.
Please help me fix these problems.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the [quickstart for Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) - python? `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib`

Comment: @Emel Yes but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have installed all the packages in the code using `pip` command. You can check package installation information with `pip show package_name`.

[image: package installation information]

**Then follow these steps:**

1. Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ( Or click the python version in the lower right corner of the interface ).

   [image]
2. Type and select **Python:Select Interpreter**.

   [image]
3. Choose the correct interpreter.

   [image]

This will solve your problem.